# Ballerina: Multiple websocket error on callback

Tags: websocket, proxy, ballerina

I've programmed a proxy server using ballerina. This proxy receives requests from customers through a websocket. The goal is that the Ballerina server collects this request and sends it to the server called "EXTRACTOR". This server processes the request and returns a response to the Ballerina server. At that time the Ballerina server does not return the response to the client who made the request, but sends the response of the "EXTRACTOR" to another server called "EXTRACTOR2" that will process the response of "EXTRACTOR". Later "EXTRACTOR2" returns the processed information to Ballerina's server and this one returns it to the client that made the request in the first instance. All the communication between Ballerina, the clients, EXTRACTOR and EXTRACTOR2 is done through websockets. The problem lies in the fact that when EXTRACTOR2 tries to return the information to Ballerina's server, it finds that it cannot because the communication has been closed.

This is my code:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;


final string ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION = "EXTRACTOR CONNECTION";
final string EXTRACTOR = "ws://localhost:9090/basic";
final string EXTRACTOR2 = "ws://localhost:9091/basic";



@http:WebSocketServiceConfig {
    path: "/api/ws"
}

service RequestService on new http:Listener(9092) {

  resource function onOpen(http:WebSocketCaller caller) {

        http:WebSocketClient wsClientEp = new(
            EXTRACTOR,
            {callbackService: ClientService1,
            readyOnConnect: false,
            maxFrameSize: 2147483648
        });
        http:WebSocketClient wsClientEp2 = new(
            EXTRACTOR2,
            {callbackService: ClientService2,
            readyOnConnect: false,
            maxFrameSize: 2147483648
        });

        caller.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, wsClientEp);
        wsClientEp.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, wsClientEp2);
        wsClientEp2.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, caller);

        var err = wsClientEp->ready();
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error calling ready on client 1", err);
        }

        err = wsClientEp2->ready();
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error calling ready on client 2", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketCaller caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {

        http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
        var err = clientEp->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }


    resource function onError(http:WebSocketCaller caller, error err) {

       http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
       var e = clientEp->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
       if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
           log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", e);
       }
       _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
       log:printError("Unexpected error hence closing the connection", err);
   }

   resource function onClose(http:WebSocketCaller caller, int statusCode, string reason) {

       http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
       var err = clientEp->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
       if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
           log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
       }
       _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
   }
}

service ClientService1 = @http:WebSocketServiceConfig {} service {

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketClient caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var err = clientEp2->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onError(http:WebSocketClient caller, error err) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var e = clientEp2->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
        if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err = e);
        }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
        log:printError("Unexpected error hense closing the connection", err);
    }

    resource function onClose(http:WebSocketClient caller, int statusCode, string reason) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var err = clientEp2->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
            if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
                log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
            }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    }
};

service ClientService2 = @http:WebSocketServiceConfig {} service {

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketClient caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var err = serverEp->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onError(http:WebSocketClient caller, error err) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var e = serverEp->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
        if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err = e);
        }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
        log:printError("Unexpected error hense closing the connection", err);
    }

    resource function onClose(http:WebSocketClient caller, int statusCode, string reason) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var err = serverEp->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
            if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
                log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
            }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    }
};

function getAssociatedClientEndpoint(http:WebSocketCaller ep) returns (http:WebSocketClient) {
    http:WebSocketClient wsClient = <http:WebSocketClient>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsClient;
}

function getAssociatedServerEndpoint(http:WebSocketClient ep) returns (http:WebSocketCaller) {
    http:WebSocketCaller wsEndpoint = <http:WebSocketCaller>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsEndpoint;
}

function getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(http:WebSocketClient ep) returns (http:WebSocketClient) {
    http:WebSocketClient wsEndpoint = <http:WebSocketClient>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsEndpoint;
}
```

When EXTRACTOR2 tries to return the information to Ballerina's server this error pops up:

```sh
Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 795, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 863, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 938, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 1018, in read_frame
    extensions=self.extensions,
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/framing.py", line 121, in read
    data = await reader(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 677, in readexactly
    raise IncompleteReadError(incomplete, n)
asyncio.streams.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 195, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "analyzer_main.py", line 39, in server
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 530, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/home/cluster/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 771, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason
Exception found
{"ok": 0, "data": "[ANALYZER] <class 'websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError'>code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason"}
```

This is the python EXTRACTOR2 code:

```py
import json
import asyncio
import websockets



from analyzer import Analyzer



analyzer = Analyzer()

print("Ready")

async def server(websocket, path):

    try:

        request_json = await websocket.recv()

        #await websocket.send(":)")

        request = json.loads(request_json)

        print("Peticion recibida")

        print(request_json)



        with open("log.txt","w+") as f:

            f.write(request_json)



        # Parsear request

        data = []

        for topic in request['data']:

            sentiment = {}

            sentiment['word'] = topic['word']

            sentiment['sentiment'] = analyzer.api_get_sentiment(topic['context'])

            data.append(sentiment)

            print("Analizado " + topic['word'])



        # Enviar respuesta

        response = {"ok": 1, "data": data}

        print(response)

        await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))



    except BaseException as exception:

        print("Exception found")

        response = {"ok": 0, "data": "[ANALYZER] " + str(type(exception)) + str(exception)}

        print(json.dumps(response))

        await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

    finally:

        print("Finished")



start_server = websockets.serve(server, "0.0.0.0", 8082)



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Can you please share the python server code as well? I wonder what is causing an abnormal closure. Can you also share ballerina logs also if any by running `ballerina run balFile.jar --b7a.log.console.loglevel=WARN`

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following Ballerina proxy:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;


final string ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION = "EXTRACTOR CONNECTION";
final string EXTRACTOR = "ws://localhost:9091/basic";
final string EXTRACTOR2 = "ws://localhost:8082";



@http:WebSocketServiceConfig {
    path: "/api/ws"
}

service RequestService on new http:Listener(9092) {

  resource function onOpen(http:WebSocketCaller caller) {

        http:WebSocketClient wsClientEp = new(
            EXTRACTOR,
            {callbackService: ClientService1,
            readyOnConnect: false,
            maxFrameSize: 2147483648
        });
        http:WebSocketClient wsClientEp2 = new(
            EXTRACTOR2,
            {callbackService: ClientService2,
            readyOnConnect: false,
            maxFrameSize: 2147483648
        });

        caller.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, wsClientEp);
        wsClientEp.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, wsClientEp2);
        wsClientEp2.setAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION, caller);

        var err = wsClientEp->ready();
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error calling ready on client 1", err);
        }

        err = wsClientEp2->ready();
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error calling ready on client 2", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketCaller caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {

        http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
        var err = clientEp->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }


    resource function onError(http:WebSocketCaller caller, error err) {

       http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
       var e = clientEp->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
       if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
           log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", e);
       }
       _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
       log:printError("Unexpected error hence closing the connection", err);
   }

   resource function onClose(http:WebSocketCaller caller, int statusCode, string reason) {

       http:WebSocketClient clientEp = getAssociatedClientEndpoint(caller);
       var err = clientEp->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
       if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
           log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
       }
       _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
   }
}

service ClientService1 = @http:WebSocketServiceConfig {} service {

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketClient caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var err = clientEp2->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onError(http:WebSocketClient caller, error err) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var e = clientEp2->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
        if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err = e);
        }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
        log:printError("Unexpected error hense closing the connection", err);
    }

    resource function onClose(http:WebSocketClient caller, int statusCode, string reason) {
        http:WebSocketClient clientEp2 = getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(caller);
        var err = clientEp2->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
            if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
                log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
            }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    }
};

service ClientService2 = @http:WebSocketServiceConfig {} service {

    resource function onText(http:WebSocketClient caller, string text, boolean finalFrame) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var err = serverEp->pushText(text, finalFrame);
        if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when sending text message", err);
        }
    }

    resource function onError(http:WebSocketClient caller, error err) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var e = serverEp->close(statusCode = 1011, reason = "Unexpected condition");
        if (e is http:WebSocketError) {
            log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err = e);
        }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
        log:printError("Unexpected error hense closing the connection", err);
    }

    resource function onClose(http:WebSocketClient caller, int statusCode, string reason) {
        http:WebSocketCaller serverEp = getAssociatedServerEndpoint(caller);
        var err = serverEp->close(statusCode = statusCode, reason = reason);
            if (err is http:WebSocketError) {
                log:printError("Error occurred when closing the connection", err);
            }
        _ = caller.removeAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    }
};

function getAssociatedClientEndpoint(http:WebSocketCaller ep) returns (http:WebSocketClient) {
    http:WebSocketClient wsClient = <http:WebSocketClient>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsClient;
}

function getAssociatedServerEndpoint(http:WebSocketClient ep) returns (http:WebSocketCaller) {
    http:WebSocketCaller wsEndpoint = <http:WebSocketCaller>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsEndpoint;
}

function getAssociatedClientEndpointFromClient(http:WebSocketClient ep) returns (http:WebSocketClient) {
    http:WebSocketClient wsEndpoint = <http:WebSocketClient>ep.getAttribute(ASSOCIATED_CONNECTION);
    return wsEndpoint;
}
```

and this python server which is a slightly modified for my testing.

```
import json
import asyncio
import websockets

print("Ready")

async def server(websocket, path):

    try:

        request_json = await websocket.recv()

        print("Peticion recibida")

        data = ["hello"]

        response = {"ok": 1, "data": data}

        print(response)

        await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

    except BaseException as exception:

        print("Exception found")

        response = {"ok": 0, "data": "[ANALYZER] " + str(type(exception)) + str(exception)}

        print(json.dumps(response))

        await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

    finally:

        print("Finished")

start_server = websockets.serve(server, "0.0.0.0", 8082)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

These work fine for me.